# Symfony2: two actions update/create in one form

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to put two actions, update and create, in one form:

```
<form id="form-add1" method="post" action="{{ entity.id ? path('entities_edit') : path('entities_new')}}">
    <div class="choice-fields">
        <div class="move-left">
            <label for="title">title</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="title" name="title" value="{{ entity.title }}" >
        </div>
        <div class="move-left">
            <div class="color-style">
                <div class="input-name">Color</div>
                <input type="color" name="color" class="color-picker" id="color" value="{{ entity.color }}" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div>
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <textarea id="description" name="description">{{ entity.description }}</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-add">
        <button type="submit" class="save">Enregistrer</button>
        <button type="reset" class="reset">Réintialiser</button>
    </div>
    <div id="here"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

And here are my functions:

`create`:

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity = new Entities();
    $form = $this->createForm(new EntitiesType(), $entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entities = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Entities')->findAll();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity->setColor($request->get('color'));
    $entity->setTitle($request->get('title'));
    $entity->setDescription($request->get('description'));
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();
    $identity = $entity->getId();
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        $json = json_encode(array(
            'entities' => $request->get('title'),
            'identity' => $identity
        ));
        $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response();
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $response->setContent($json);
        return $response;
    }
    return $this->redirectToRoute('entities_index');
}
```

`update`:

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Entities $entity, $id)
{
    $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Entities')->find($id);
    $entity->setTitle($request->get('title'));
    $entity->setColor($request->get('color'));
    $entity->setDescription($request->get('description'));
    $em->persist($entity);
    $em->flush();

    $json = json_encode(array());
    return $this->redirectToRoute('Entities_index');
}
```

My routes:

```
entities_new:
path:     /new
defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entities:new" }
methods:  [GET, POST]

entities_edit:
path:     /{id}/edit
defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entities:edit" }
methods:  [GET, POST]
```

When an entity is called to be `updated`, a new entity is `added`. Could anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

The signature for the `update` method is wrong. It should be either this:

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Entities $entity)
```

or this

```
public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
```

In the first case you are using the `ParamConverter` feature to automatically load an entity via the id from `Request`, in which case you **don't have** use the `find($id)` method because the entity is already loaded.

In the second case you are loading the entity from the db via a manual `find` method.

In your signature, the $id is defined as third parameter so it will always be null, so it will always load a new entity. But you also modify the existing entity, so basically assigning it a null ID.

That's why it gets inserted.

Comment: thank you for your answer , sorry i really a beginer  so how  how can i fix tht my entity.id get the id    and not the null    thank u

Comment: Please re-read carefully my answer. The explanation is there. If, after that, you still have no idea how to change your code, read this page also: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html. If, after that, you STILL have no idea then you should probably pair coding for a while.

Answer (score 0):

In your edit method remove the 2nd param, so that you just have request and id. Then update your twig 'entities_edit' path to `path('entities_edit', {'id':entityId})` you'll need to add the template var "entityId" to your form page